# Request.referer always points to host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, rvm, passenger

It seems like `request.referer` or `request.env['HTTP_REFERER']` does not provide the right referer on my setup. 
Referer is always the host of my applicaton (`http://mydomain.tld`). I expected a different referer based on my previous page like `http://mydomain.tld/tasks/1` or `http://mydomain.tld/tasks`.

This is my virtualhost setup:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName referer
 RailsEnv development

 DocumentRoot /var/www/referer/public
 <Directory /var/www/referer/public>
   Options None
   AllowOverride None
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

```
# passenger.conf
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
 PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/passenger-3.0.11
 PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p125/ruby
</IfModule>

# passenger.load
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/passenger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
```

I am using apache with passenger-rvm. Is there something wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argh, my bad. I installed a new browser plugin [Script no](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/noscript/). That was the reason why my referer was unset ...